# Duplicating point within shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

How do you duplicate a point within a single feature class using Python? I have a partial sample script below, but in a nutshell, I want to duplicate a point, copy it into the same shapefile, and populate the fields with user-provided strings. I suspect this is elementary, but I'm new at this and am frustrated with loops and cursors.

```
# Script tool will take a point file and allow the user to duplicate a single point
# while updating necessary field information. The purpose is not to delete or overwrite
# the original point object, but rather to add a duplicate point with the new information.
# This allows historical context for a point that spatially never changes, but who's 
# fields are dynamic. No information is hard-coded.

import arcpy
# set up input variables for target folder and target dataset.
targetFC=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  # this is the point file
targetKeyField=arcpyGetparameterAsText(1)  # this is the key field in the point file
newKeyID=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  # must be duplicate of a string in targetKeyField
newField2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
newField3 = arcpy.GetParamaterAsText(4)

# Add new fields to table
in_table = targetFC
field_name2 = "Field_2"
field_name3 = "Field_3"
field_type = "TEXT"
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, field_name2, field_type)
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, field_name3, field_type)

# Loop through targetFC to find a match between newKeyID and a string in targetKeyField
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(targetFC, [targetKeyField, "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:

     # insertCursor based on the match; duplicate the point in the table
          # Populate the new cursor with the new parameters (newField2, newField3, etc)
     # Error if the newParcelID does not match a string in the targetKeyField
     # User is brought back to enter a new newKeyID string.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the geometry object into memory directly from the SearchCursor, using a SQL query to limit the cursor to a single point instead of looping through them all, and then inserting it with an InsertCursor.

It's not possible to open a prompt for a user to enter a different value when running a script as a script tool (which it looks like you're trying to create, given the `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()` calls), so in the code below I've used `arcpy.AddError()` and `sys.exit()`. This will stop the tool with an error message, and when the user closes the failed tool they should be presented with the parameter-specification window again for easy resubmission.

```
# Define SQL query to select point to be copied
query = ''' "{0}" = '{1}' '''.format(targetKeyField, newKeyID)

# Obtain geometry with a SearchCursor, or error if non-existent
geom_list = [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(targetFC, ['SHAPE@'], query)]
if len(geom_list) > 0:
    geom = geom_list[0]
else:
    arcpy.AddError('''Point "{0}"='{1}' doesn't exist!'''.format(targetKeyField, newKeyID))
    import sys
    sys.exit()

# Use an InsertCursor to append geometry with new field values
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(targetFC, ['SHAPE@', targetKeyField, field_name2, field_name3]) as ic:
    new_row = [geom, newKeyID, newField2, newField3]
    ic.insertRow(new_row)
```